# A change to the 'required' value of a site column not reflected in content type

Tags: content-type, column, site-column

As title suggests, I had a site column defined in the xml of a content type.

The site column was required. I have just changed the definition of this field (it is not defined anywhere else in the solution) so that required = false.

Under 'Site Columns' of the Site Settings page, I can see this change has been implemented as I'd expect.

However, on the Site Content Type it still appears as a mandatory field. Is it not possible to push this change out to all content types that reference the column? This will need to be done on several environments so as you can expect I need it to be as 'automated' as possible. Deleting the content type is not an option.

NOTE: I did remove the site column manually from the content type and re-added it, it is now optional. As I say though, that's a far from ideal approach.

Answer (score 1):

If the column exists Under 'Site Columns' of the Site Settings page you should be able to modify it in browser and check the button that propagates changes. This should set everything to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. I had to remove content type and column from the library completely and add it again because the required field was never changed back to optional.